# Html Table returns undefine when looping through cell rows?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(document).on("click", "#devSaveBtn", function() {
  var answer = window.confirm("Save changes");
  if (answer) {
    // * Table variable
    var table = document.getElementById("TableRows");

    // * Input variable
    var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");

    // * Loop to get the input & dropdown values
    for (var i = 0; i < getInput.length; i++)
      console.log(getInput[i].id, " => Input", i, " = ", getInput[i].value);

    for (var i = 0, row; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
      // * iterate through rows
      // * rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop

      for (var j = 0, col; (col = row.cells[j]); j++) {
        // * iterate through columns
        // * columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop

        var ObjType = [table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML];
        var Name = [table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML];
        var Business = [table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML];
        var Project = [table.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML];
        var Deployer_Candidate = [table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML];
        var Description = [table.rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML];
        console.log(col);
        console.log("Name = " + Name.value);
      }
    }
  }
  // * else display service message
  else {
    console.log("Service Cancel");
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="TableRows">
  <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->
  <tbody id="recordRow0" style="display:none; border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
    <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
      <td class="noncomponentswidth">
        <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record" value="0">
                                                    <span><i style="font-size:18px;"
                                                            class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
                                                </button>
      </td>
      <!-- * Record intializing *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>


      <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
      <div id="container">
        <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
          <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
            <option value="TP">TP</option>
            <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
            <option value="Package">Package</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </div>


      <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
        <p>
          <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
          <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder="" class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
        </p>
      </td>

      <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
        <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name" placeholder="" style="display: none;">
        <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
          <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
          <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
          <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
          <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
          <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
          <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
          <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
          <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">
            CorporateFinancialServices
          </option>
          <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
          <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
          <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
          <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
          <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
          <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
          <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
          <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
          <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
          <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
          <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
          <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
          <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
          <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
          <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
          <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
          <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
        </select>

      </td>

      <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
        <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck" placeholder="">
      </td>


      <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
        <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

          <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
          <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)
          </option>
          <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
          <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
          </option>
          <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
          <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)
          </option>
        </select>

      </td>

      <!-- * Input for Description *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
        <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder="" class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;" </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to loop through all the rows in my table and get the drop down & Input values from each row so I can insert them into my DB. It returns undefine though when I log the information. I can use the commented out loop to get the information but that loop doesn't iterate over multiple rows. The goal is to have a variable for instance the Name variable get all the row values with under the column name "Name". So when it inserts back into the Database it insert it row one 1, row two with 4, etc. [image]

Comment: You're missing the  `}` for the `if` statement  in the JS code.

Comment: Sorry it was in my code miss it when copying it over onto the page.

Comment: How do you lose a character when doing copy/paste?

Comment: I'm sorry I Just miss it when I was copying it over. Do you have any thoughts on how to solve the undefined issue?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `.innerHTML` if you want to get the value of an input in the cell. Find the input by its class and use `.value` to get its value.

Use `.value` when setting the variable, then you don't need to use it again when calling `console.log()`.

There's also no good reason to put each value into a single-element array.

And you don't need to iterate over the columns, since you're accessing them by index when you set the variables.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#devSaveBtn", function() {
  var answer = window.confirm("Save changes");
  if (answer) {
    // * Table variable
    var table = document.getElementById("TableRows");

    // * Input variable
    var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");

    // * Loop to get the input & dropdown values
    for (var i = 0; i < getInput.length; i++)
      console.log(getInput[i].id, " => Input", i, " = ", getInput[i].value);

    for (var i = 0, row; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
      // * iterate through rows
      // * rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop

      var ObjType = row.cells[2].querySelector('.vcheck').value;
      var Name = row.cells[3].querySelector('.vcheck').value;
      var Business = row.cells[4].querySelector('.vcheck').value;
      var Project = row.cells[5].querySelector('.vcheck').value;
      var Deployer_Candidate = row.cells[6].querySelector('.vcheck').value;
      var Description = row.cells[7].querySelector('.vcheck').value;
      console.log("Name = " + Name);
    }
  }
  // * else display service message
  else {
    console.log("Service Cancel");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="devSaveBtn">Save</button>
<table id="TableRows">
  <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->
  <tbody id="recordRow0" style="border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
    <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
      <td class="noncomponentswidth">
        <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record" value="0">
          <span><i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
        </button>
      </td>
      <!-- * Record intializing *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>
      <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
      <div id="container">
        <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
          <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
            <option value="TP">TP</option>
            <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
            <option value="Package">Package</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </div>

      <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
        <p>
          <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
          <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder="" class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
        </p>
      </td>

      <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
        <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name" placeholder="" style="display: none;">
        <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
          <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
          <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
          <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
          <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
          <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
          <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
          <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
          <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">
            CorporateFinancialServices
          </option>
          <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
          <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
          <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
          <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
          <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
          <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
          <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
          <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
          <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
          <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
          <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
          <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
          <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
          <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
          <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
          <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
          <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
        </select>

      </td>

      <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
        <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck" placeholder="">
      </td>


      <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
        <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

          <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
          <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)
          </option>
          <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
          <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
          </option>
          <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
          </option>
          <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
          <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)
          </option>
        </select>

      </td>

      <!-- * Input for Description *-->
      <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
        <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder="" class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;" </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As an aside, IDs are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't use the same ID in every row of a table.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252684/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-html-table-returns-undefine-when-looping-through); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.